# 2nd Column fill remaining screen height not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navbar with a fixed height, underneath a `control` div with also a fixed height and below that I have another div `calendar`. calendar is scrollable. I want the calendar height to have the remaining screen height below `control` and the bottom of the screen. This way the window is not scrollable, only the calendar is scrollable. However setting `height: 100%` does not work and `flex: 1` neither.

This is what I have when I set the height of `calendar` to a fixed height but as I explained I want the height to be the rest of the screen size.

Any Idea?

```css
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: indianred;
}

.window {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.control  {
  height: 100px;
  background: khaki;
}

.calendar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.main {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
<div class="window">

  <div class="control">

  </div>
  
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main">
  
        

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean when you scroll down you want a full height calendar?

Comment: No I mean for example when my screnn is 1000 px high, then my calendar should have the height 850px (because navbar is 50px high and controls 100px -> 1000 - 50 - 100 = 850). So I should always fill the remaining space under the control div and the bottom of the screen.

Comment: This way the window isn't scrollable, only the calendar inside the window is scrollable

Comment: jQuery can solve this you can manipulate css example: $('.calendar').css("height", "850px");

Comment: getting the viewport height using javascript: var windowHeight = window.innerHeight; then use conditional statement let say: if(windowHeight == 100px){}

Comment: I can probably do it with JavaScript but I thought there would be a css way?

Comment: @Jonas   so you want the calendar to fill the rest of the screen height? and be able to scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Run this Code below: 
I used `height: calc()` method full height of the screen minus 150px for nav and controls.

```css
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: indianred;
}

.window {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.control {
  height: 100px;
  background: khaki;
}

.calendar {
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.main {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
<div class="window">
  <div class="control">
  </div>
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work almost good but there is a little offset so that the window scrolls a tiny bit. However if I don't find a better solution I will go with this. Thank you!